# Why this pagination doesn't work when using Kaminari?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

Here's error and my codes. I'm using `Kaminari`

```
Error:  undefined method `model_name' for #<Array:0x0000001d5abeb0>
73:     <%= page_entries_info(@communities).html_safe %>
```

**view**

```
<%= page_entries_info(@communities).html_safe %>
```

**Community controller**

UPDATE*   This is how I'm fetching now

```
    @search = Community.search do  
    fulltext params[:search]
        with(:location_id, params[:location]) if params[:location].to_i >0           
        with(:type_id, params[:type]) if params[:type].to_i >0
        order_by :cached_votes_up, :desc
        paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
    end

    @communities = @search.results
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **kaminari** and **will_paginate** together, you will definitely face this error. In short, **kaminari** and **will_paginate** are incompatible to each other.

If you are using `rails_admin` (which uses kaminari for pagination) and also using `will_paginate`, you will need to add the following code to one of the initializers under config directory or you can create a new file, let say with name 'will_paginate' add the code, and place it into initializers directory.

```
if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationMethods
        def per(value = nil) per_page(value) end
        def total_count() count end
      end
    end
    module CollectionMethods
      alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not using will_paginate at all.

Comment: I was using version 0.13.0 until an hour ago, it didn't have this error then. But previous version had the error with another locale problem. So I updated it to 0.14.1 but this new error came out.

Comment: @users = User.scoped.page(params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")

Comment: Try , `<%= page_entries_info(@communities, :entry_name => 'model_name').html_safe %>` where model_name is your model's name.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with your translation:

```
"%{total} total records. Displaying　%{first} - %{last}"
```

Here it is expecting 3 arguments when you call this translation:
the variables `total`, `first` and `last` but "you" give only these 2 variables: `entry_name` & `count`

Can you provide more info about the `page_entries_info` method please?

## EDIT:

As you commented, https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/kaminari/helpers/action_view_extension.rb#L102 **Line 102-109**:
You need to have in your .yml translation file(s) something like this:

```
en:
  helpers:
    page_entries_info:
      one_page:
        display_entries: "%{count} total records for %{entry_name}."
      more_pages:
        display_entries: "%{total} total records. Displaying　%{first} - %{last}"
```

Comment: I'm using the gem called Kaminari. It does everything.  here's source code.  https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/kaminari/helpers/action_view_extension.rb  Please take a look at line 88

Comment: @HUSTEN I updated my answer, hope this helps! If not, please post what you've set in your yml translation file

Comment: Now another error came out:(  undefined method `model_name' for #<Array:0x0000001a4ddc98>